# Automating manual git and building process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git

I have a `node.js_server` which has a child folder from where it serves a [react](https://reactjs.org/) frontend. The following is the directory hierarchy representation:

```
node.js_server
  - react_frontend_build
```

Now to push any react frontend change I follow so many manual steps:

1. make a change in the frontend git repository
2. `git commit` and `git push` the change
3. generate a [react build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) & copy the generated files
4. paste and replace files in the `node.js_server`'s `react_frontend_build` folder

Now, the `node.js_server` has updated changes in the `react_frontend_build` directory.

5. I `git commit` and `git push` those changes so my [continuous delivery](https://www.heroku.com/continuous-delivery) pipeline gets triggered and the frontend changes are deployed.

> These are so many manual steps for a single frontend change to propagate from coding to deployment!

In short - the parent git repository (`node.js_server`)'s subdirectory (`react_frontend_build`) is actually a directory (react build) from another dependent (frontend) git repository.

This is a very normal scenario when you are working on a [MERN stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mern-stack/) app. So, I expect many might have seen this kind of problem and probably might have solutions for it!

How do I automate this whole process here?

Answer (score 1):

I've built similar things to get to DevOps with multiple repos.  The techniques are not that different to building out a regular, single-repo DevOps pipeline.

My first step is to build a script that does all the things you're doing now -- reach into the other project, run the build process, and either pass in the path or then cp the files into place.

Once this script reliably works on your machine, we can look at doing this in a build process like GitHub Actions.  The magic here is during the build you need to check out the latest copy of the other repo.  A submodule is a tempting choice here, but is likely more complicated than necessary as the submodule is a link to a particular commit which you need to keep updated.  I find it's easier to just drive the git cli to checkout the other repo to a convenient folder.  The magic sauce is ensuring the service account running the build has at least read access to the other repo.  If you're using one service account for all your builds, it already does.  :D